# SQL : How to check if my schedule is ok

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a DB which looks like this :

```
FromDate                     ToDate         ProfileUID 
2017-02-10 07:00:00   2017-02-10 15:30:00   TB_D 
2017-02-09 23:00:00   2017-02-10 07:00:00   ZK_D 
2017-02-09 17:30:00   2017-02-09 23:00:00   DL_D 
2017-02-09 07:00:00   2017-02-09 17:30:00   AM_D 
2017-02-08 23:00:00   2017-02-09 07:00:00   CK_D 
2017-02-08 17:30:00   2017-02-08 23:00:00   DJ_N
```

This DB is often modified manually and some errors can be done by user.

I'm trying to do an SQL query to check if the schedule is ok, which means I would like to know until when my records are (here we filled only for the two next days) and if there are no "black holes" in the schedule, meaning there is a period with no profileUID filled.

What I have so far :

```
SELECT *,LAG (ToDate) OVER (PARTITION BY FromDate ORDER BY FromDate) 
FROM `dashboardcalendar` 
WHERE FromDate>= NOW() 
ORDER BY `dashboardcalendar`.`FromDate`  ASC
```

Comment: My DB is 10.1.14-MariaDB

Comment: What do you mean by "What I have so far"? There are no window functions in MariaDB 10.1.14, the were added in 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Given that you can't use window functions on your version of MariaDB, try this:

```
SELECT FromDate, ToDate, ProfileUID, next_FromDate, last_ToDate,
CASE WHEN next_record_uid is null then 'Warning - Gap after' end warn1,
CASE WHEN prev_record_uid is null then 'Warning - Gap before' end warn2
FROM (
SELECT t1.FromDate, t1.ToDate, t1.ProfileUID, 
t2.ProfileUID next_record_uid, 
t3.ProfileUID prev_record_uid 
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t1.ToDate = t2.FromDate
LEFT JOIN table t3
ON t1.FromDate = t3.ToDate
)
```

This does not account for overlaps in time - it will give a false positive warning if two time periods overlap.

Original answer:

I'd use LEAD as well as LAG, and then wrap in another select to do the comparison:

```
SELECT FromDate, ToDate, ProfileUID, next_FromDate, last_ToDate,
CASE WHEN ToDate < next_FromDate then 'Warning - Gap after' end warn1,
CASE WHEN FromDate > last_ToDate then 'Warning - Gap before' end warn2
FROM (
SELECT FromDate, ToDate, ProfileUID, 
LEAD(FromDate,1) OVER (ORDER BY FromDate) next_FromDate,
LAG(FromDate,1) OVER (ORDER BY FromDate) last_ToDate
FROM table
)
```

You should not need to partition, it sounds like from your description that each record covers a distinct period of time so there's nothing to group on.

Comment: You cannot do it on 10.1.14. Window functions were introduced in MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: So even OP's original code won't even work given the information he added after I submitted this answer, cool.